# How to define multiple dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From the yahoo finance api, I can get EURUSD and AUDUSD 15 min data, yet I want to use a for loop to define them (i.e. 2 dataframe), so that I can run the correlation of multiple df.

Ideally,

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(yf.download(tickers = EURUSD ,start=Start_Date, end=End_Date, interval = '15m'))


df2=pd.DataFrame(yf.download(tickers = AUDUSD ,start=Start_Date, end=End_Date, interval = '15m'))
```

But I need a for loop to define these 2 df

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf


#"YYYY-MM-DD"
Start_Date= '2021-05-03'
End_Date= '2021-05-04'

list = pd.Series(['EURUSD=X', 'AUDUSD=X'],index=['1','2'])


for i in list:
    
  data = yf.download(tickers = i ,start=Start_Date, end=End_Date, interval = '15m')
  df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  
    
  print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do so will be to store both of the data frames in a single list.

```py
dfList = []

for i in list:
    
  data = yf.download(tickers = i ,start=Start_Date, end=End_Date, interval = '15m')
  df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  dfList.append(df)
```

Or, you can even use comprehension

```py
dfList = [pd.DataFrame(yf.download(tickers = i ,start=Start_Date, end=End_Date, interval = '15m')) 
          for i in list]
```

Now you can access `df1` as `dfList[0]` and `df2` as `dfList[1]`

Comment: Accepted Thank you!